# Is it safe to visit any website in TOR when the Security Bar is set at Maximum? (Safest)

Tags: http, phishing, tor, websites

Someone has sent me a link on Tor which when visited instantly read that the website itself was not available and that apparently the link is broken somehow. When using Tor i use the option "Safest"

But im a little paranoid that i clicked on something which was risky. Am i instantly exposed now to the apparent "hacker" ? Could have also been a wrong copied link but i can't be too sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

The "Safest" setting is in relation to the tor browser and it will only allow features that a static site would have.  Thus it will disable things such a javascript, and etc.

This will improve your security posture, (at a major cost of functionality) but is not a guarantee against compromise from websites or strategies to defeat tor's anonymity model.  The Tor browser and tor network are designed to complement each other so it is more secure than just using tor from a random browser.

There is not enough info in the question to indicate if you were compromised or not.

If you looking to increase your security posture, I recommend using [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/doc/index.en.html) in A [VM](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/index.en.html).